# Use of "as well" in the middle of the sentence

Tags: grammar, word-order, syntactic-analysis

I was wondering if the use of "as well" in the middle of the sentence is correct in formal English.

Here is the particular sentence I am writing:

> I got ample opportunities to communicate with a large audience and individuals as well, which enhanced my oral communication skills.

Comment: I don't think it's incorrect, but I would rephrase it as "... with large audiences and individuals alike..." No real reason (which is why I'm not posting it as an answer), just looks and feels better to me.

Comment: The agreement in 'I got ample opportunities to communicate with a large audience' is disconcerting. Is 'I got ample opportunities to communicate with individuals, and also once addressed a large audience ...' intended?

Comment: Any reason you like to use both *and* & *as well?*

Comment: In my comment, 'and' is the tack-on-[any-old]-associated-info sentence-connector, while 'also' emphasises the point of additional supportive material. I wouldn't drop 'also'. Though I'm not too clear about what OP actually means. One or several/many audiences? And did he take all those opportunities?

Comment: It looks like a clumsy usage to me. If you insist ***as well***, you might improve things slightly by parenthesizing *(and individuals as well)*, but I'd rather rephrase to *"I had ample opportunity to communicate **with both large audiences and individuals**, which enhanced my oral communication skills."*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I noticed that you used opportunity with ample. Is writing 'ample opportunities' wrong?

Comment: @Manan Jain: The plural form isn't actually "wrong", but as you'll see from [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+ample+opportunities%2Chad+ample+opportunity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20ample%20opportunities%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20ample%20opportunity%3B%2Cc0), idiomatically we came to prefer the singular 150 years ago, and that preference has continued to become stronger ever since. Ignore anyone who claims a distinction in *meaning* - it really is just *established idiomatic preference*, pure and simple.

Comment: Your listener will certainly ask "As well as what?" If you have an answer, it's not a bad sentence, but as it stands it's ambiguous.

Comment: It probably refers to a prior sentence. Please give us the two preceding sentences for context. As well, I recall another question here with exactly that same quoted sentence.

Comment: On a slightly different note, I'd look for an alternative to "I got" e.g. "I received", "I was offered" or even "I had".

Answer (score 1):

I checked the BNC (British National Corpus), and I have found a number of such occurrences:

> Perverse unreasonable Pamela, begone from my sight and know as well
>   how to behave in a hopeful prospect...
>
> ...many actually had art galleries and museums under their care as
>   well, providing an early example of multi-media provision...

The comma is also not obligatory. Certainly, the most common cas is the structure *as well as*.

Between, you can use it at the beginning as well:

> As well as Germany, Japan, Switzerland, Sweden, Spain, Canada, Italy
>   and Holland all dump the deadly stuff here to be converted back into
>   more nuclear fuel.

Answer (score 0):

"as well" is fine, but you need to put a comma after "audience" to make it clear that "as well" applies only to "individuals".  Otherwise it can be taken to refer back to whatever you might have  said in the prior sentence.  (I did x, and, additionallly, I had ample opportunities .......) that is, the "as well" in your example could be taken as a sentence modifier.

Answer (score 0):

The use of **as well** in the middle of sentence is quite fine, it is commonly used after the subject of the sentence. For instance,

*We liked speaking to people of different cultures. She as well adores it. or Mary as well adores it.*